# Python 2.7->2.6 problems

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-2.6

I'm a beginner with Python and Django.

I'm setting up a program i've written locally. After almost finishing getting the app to work on the server, i've learned that the server is running python 2.6, while my local system runs 2.7. This is seemingly giving me problems when retrieving paramters from urls.

I'm using a server from Openshift. I don't know much about servers, but my current setup is that I have a local clone of the file, and I work on everything locally, and the push them via git to the server. The server was set up using a predefined quick setup from inside the Openshift interface.

I'm using the following urlpattern, which works just fine locally on my computer.

```
   url(r'^website/(?P<url>[:\w/\-.]+)$', 'page'),
```

However, on my server version i'm running into some problems. The following url, returns two different urls to the view, depending on whether i'm on the server or running local.

```
    #when using this url
    website/http://example.com

    #local view called page, retrives this argument 
    http://example.com

#server version retrieves almost the same, but with one / in the beginner less. 
http:/example.com
```

It seems to me that a backslash is being chopped off somewhere. How can I change it to parse the argument with both backslashes?

```
    # the receiving view
    def page(request, url):
        p = Page.objects.get(url=url)
    domain = p.website.url
    return render_to_response('seo/page.html', {'domain': domain, 'page': p},    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The local version is returning the desired page just fine. The server version returns this:

```
     DoesNotExist at /website/http:/coverme.dk/collections/iphone-sleeves-covers
```

I noticed that one of the backslashes in http:// was missing here, and assumed the error was based on it being sent to the view incorrectly.

I've just tested with an url that does not exist in the database on the local version, and it displays the error message correctly.

I've also double checked that the object for url='http://coverme.dk/collections/iphone-sleeves-covers' actually exists. I've also checked with several others.

I've experimented with messing around with the input url, and it seems to working just fine, except when I use double, triple of more backslashes. All backslashes succesively after the first are ignored in the url.

```
/website/http://////coverme.dk////collections/iphone-sleeves-covers 
#gives the same as 
/website/http:/coverme.dk/collections/iphone-sleeves-covers.
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated. A link to some documentation that could help me out would be greatly appreciated as well.

EDIT: Updating django solved this issue.

Comment: Are you **100%** certain that you are using the same path in the request URLs between local and production? Because the regular expression engine *did not change* between Python versions 2.6 and 2.7, not to cause such a difference.

Comment: Whatever is causing the difference, I can tell you right here, right now, that that url pattern is **not** the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! The url patterns are completely identical. I'm pushing the changes through git, so everything on the server should be identical to what I have locally.

Comment: Then show us the view; how are you determining that the parameter differs?

Comment: When you say "on the server", do you mean when running the django dev-server on your server, or do you mean by linking it to a deployment server (such as apache)? And if the latter, can you show us how you configured it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I've added the view as well as my reasoning.

Comment: @yuvi - I've added a description of the server I'm using.

Comment: Have you tried using a URL that doesn't exist in your database in your local development server? Perhaps the error message constructs the URL incorrectly, on both Python 2.6 and 2.7..

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the object for `url='http://coverme.dk/collections/iphone-sleeves-covers'` actually exists in the database on the production server?

Comment: Last but not least, are the versions of Django the same? And take into account that a misconfigured front-end server can alter how a URL is interpreted. Can we see the exact URL you are requesting? Are the slashes in the URL parameter correctly escaped?

Comment: In fact, the more I think about it, the more sure I am that it must be the front-end server at fault here. If you request `/website/http%3A%2F%2Fcoverme.dk%2Fcollections%2Fiphone-sleeves-covers` (as you really *should*) and the frontend *decodes* the URL before passing it on to Django, then Django will first normalize the URL from `/website/http://coverme.dk/collections/iphone-sleeves-covers` to `/website/http:/coverme.dk/collections/iphone-sleeves-covers` (removing the redundant double `//`), then not find a matching URL path because it won't match your pattern.

Comment: If you are using literal slashes in the URL, then you cannot do that. **Encode** the slashes; slashes there to deliniate for path segments, only encoded slashes can be part of the path segment.

Comment: Using /website/http%3A%2F%2Fcoverme.dk%2Fcollections%2Fiphone-sleeves-covers as the url returns: The requested URL /website/http://coverme.dk/collections/iphone-sleeves-covers was not    found on this server. Django version on the server is 1.4 and the one being used locally is 1.5.1. I've still to understand why i'm seeing different results locally and on the server, but i'm starting to think i should just switch to an url pattern that doesn't use //?

Comment: There's significant difference between Django 1.4 and 1.5, I suggest either updating the server or downgrading your local environment.

Comment: @Exelian Ok, good to know, was not aware of that. I'll look into updating the server.

Comment: Updating Django solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

From [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001827/python-2-7-2-6-problems/22725749#comment29781800_20001827) by the author of the question:

> Using /website/http%3A%2F%2Fcoverme.dk%2Fcollections%2Fiphone-sleeves-covers as the url returns: The requested URL /website/coverme.dk/collections/iphone-sleeves-covers was not found on this server. Django version on the server is 1.4 and the one being used locally is 1.5.1. I've still to understand why i'm seeing different results locally and on the server, but i'm starting to think i should just switch to an url pattern that doesn't use //?
>
> Updating Django solved the issue for me

Comment: I just flagged this as *not an answer* before I realised you are quoting the OP in the question. It'd have been better had you made this a community wiki and gave it a little more context.